# Scala string pattern matching by multiple possible groups

Tags: string, scala, pattern-matching, scala-collections

Given an input `Map[String,String]` such as

```
val in = Map("name1"                -> "description1",
             "name2.name22"         -> "description 22",
             "name3.name33.name333" -> "description 333")
```

what is a simple way to extract each *name* and each *description* and feed them into a method such as

```
def process(description: String, name: String*): Unit = name match {
  case Seq(n)     =>  // find(n).set(description)
  case Seq(n,m)   =>  // find(n).find(m).set(description)
  case Seq(n,m,o) =>  // find(n).find(m).find(o).set(description)
  case _          =>  // possible error reporting
}
```

Many Thanks

Comment: I guess you mean `def process(tuple: (String, String)*)` or `def process(description: String, name: String)`, as either you can to process each entry one by one, or process all entries at once (which mean more than one 1 description).

Comment: @applicius one map entry at a time, keys arrayed.

Comment: What's the return type?

Comment: @applicius note update in question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the splat operator `_*`:

```
val in = Map("name1" -> "description1",
  "name2.name22" -> "description 22",
  "name3.name33.name333" -> "description 333")

def process(description: String, name: String*) = ???


in.map { x =>
  process(x._2, x._1.split("\\."): _*)
}
```

Note that `*` parameters must come last in the function signature (otherwise the compiler won't be able to decide where to stop).

From the REPL:

```
scala>   def process(description: String, name: String*) = {
     |     name.foreach(println)
     |     println(description)
     |   }
process: (description: String, name: String*)Unit

scala>   in.map { x =>
      |    process(x._2, x._1.split("\\."): _*)
      |   }
    name1
    description1
    name2
    name22
    description 22
    name3
    name33
    name333
    description 333
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```scala
in foreach { case (ns, d) => process(d, ns.split("\\."): _*) }
```